# toggle nav bar when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the script to create a navbar,
its only can make dropdown menu opened only when it hovered, the problem is when this accessed by mobile browser, dropdown menu cannot open, how to modify this script in order to make dropdown menu open when clicked the parent menu

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse offset w-100" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <div class="row w-100 mr-0">
              <div class="col-lg-7 pr-0">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav center_nav pull-right">
                  <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                      aria-expanded="false">Paket</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="category.html">Pestgre</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                      aria-expanded="false">Blog</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="single-blog.html">Blog Details</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                      aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="tracking.html">Tracking</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="elements.html">Elements</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: provide relevant CSS and JavaScript

Comment: Mobile browsers don't have hover functionality (it's translated into a click) and as Vepthy said, we need the remaining CSS/JS to better help solve your problem.

Comment: there are so many css/js script used, basically this from bootstrap template.

Answer (score 0):

For a mobile version, I would use a hamburger menu (the three lines if you didn't know). You can find the icon or make it your self. In javascript or jquery, say

```
const getMenu = document.getElementById("menuButtonsId"); //be sure to call this code after after the document has loaded, or else javascript won't find the button or icon.
getMenu.onclick(function(){
  if (the menu is closed) {
    open the menu
  } else {
    close the menu
  }
})
```

I don't know much about jquery, but I think you can do something like this

```
$("#menuButtonsId").click(function() {
  if (the menu is closed) {
    open the menu
  } else {
    close the menu
  }
})
```

Just fill out the place holder text that I put in the code. I hoped that answered your question!